# How to remove the background-activated on ion-datetime?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, less

**.item-datetime | ion-datetime**

When you click on the ion-datetime tag it does a background effect on the parent ion-item tag (not working with !important).

```
.item-datetime {
    --ion-item-background-activated: transparent;
    --ion-item-background: transparent;
    --ion-item-background-focused: transparent;
    --ion-item-background-hover: transparent;

    --ion-item-background-activated: transparent;
    --background: transparent;
    --background-activated: transparent;
    --background-focused: transparent;
    --background-hover: transparent;
    background: transparent;

    --background-activated-opacity: 0;
    --background-focused-opacity: 0;
    --background-hover-opacity: 0;
    --transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to remove the background effect

```
--ripple-color: transparent;
--background-hover: transparent;
```

Comment: --ripple-color is working on ion-item (effect to ion-datetime). thank you.